# Generalised limits via derivatives of integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, regularization

Assuming that $f$ is a continuous function, we have that

$$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int f(t)\,dt.$$

Assuming instead that $f$ has a removable singularity at $x=a$, and is otherwise continuous, we have that

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = \left.\frac{d}{dx} \int f(t)\,dt\right|_{x=a},$$
where the integral is either an improper Riemann integral, or a Lebesgue or Gauge integral.

But what if the singularity at $x=a$ is not removable? For instance, we have that

$$\left.\frac{d}{dx}\int \sin\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)\,dt\right|_{x=a}=0,$$

but the singularity at $x=0$ of $\sin(1/x)$ is not removable.

How does this relate to other notions of generalised limit, such as Cesaro's or Abel's?

[edit]

For clarification, the procedure above is, given a function $f$, and a real number $a$, to consider the following limit
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\int_a^{a+\epsilon}f(t)\,dt}{\epsilon}.$$
The result you get from $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ and $a = 0$ comes from the fact that the integral of $f$ has a removable singularity at $x=0$, on which $\int f$ can still be differentiated, albeit the resulting derivative is discontinuous.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but the following survey paper might be worth looking at: Peter Bullen, [*Non-absolute integrals in the twentieth century*](https://www.emis.de/proceedings/Toronto2000/papers/bullen.pdf), AMS Special Session on Nonabsolute Integration, 23-24 September 2000, 27 pages (has 195 references). Perhaps also the following paper, although it doesn't appear to be available online: Ralph Henstock, *A short history of integration theory*, **Southeast Asian Bulletin of Mathematics** 12 #2 (1988), 75-95 (has 262 references).

Comment: As far as I understand the question, this seems to be simply a rewording of Cesàro convergence, right?

Comment: An addition to the comment of @DaveLRenfro: the paper by Henstok [is available](http://www.seams-bull-math.ynu.edu.cn/downloadfile.jsp?filemenu=_198802&filename=198802_1530365150482.tar) as a compressed archive of .TIFF scans from the [Southeast Asian Mathematical Society Bulletin web site](http://www.seams-bull-math.ynu.edu.cn/index.jsp), not from the Springer Verlag (the current distributor) web site.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Not sure, but the function $\frac{3 \cos(1/x^3)}{x^2}$ is unbounded, while the Cesaro limit only works for bounded functions. The generalised limit for this function at $x=0$ is $0$

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thank you. This is an interesting reference

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Thank you for the reference

Comment: @jkabrg: I see, you're more interested in gauge integral.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something. But by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\left.\frac{d}{dx}\right|_{x=a} \int^x \sin(1/t) dt = \sin(1/a)$. So I don't see how sending $a\to 0$ helps recover some kind of limit. Cesàro integration involves an extra averaging before taking the limit.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Hopefully my edit will help clarify

Answer (score 1):

I think that the concept of the limit of a distribution might be relevant. This can be defined elementarily as follows: a distribution $f$ on, say, $]0,1]$ has limit $a$ at zero if it has the form $D^p F$ (distributional derivative) near zero, where $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{F(x)}{x^p}=\frac a{p!}.$$

Every continuous on ${]0,1}$ function is a distribution and it can happen that it has a limit in the distributional sense, but not in the classical one.  Thus we have $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sin x=0$ in the distributional sense (forgive me for switching to limits at infinity for the purpose of this example).

The case where $p=1$ gives that the limit of a continuous $f$ is $a$ if $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {F(x)}x = 0$ where $F$is a primitive (application: $f(x)= \sin{\frac 1 x}$).

Comment: Sorry, this should really be a comment.